# Different key code behavior in xterm and curses

Tags: c, keyboard, ncurses

Running the following code to determine the correct key code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> using curses gives me two different outputs (both servers are running Debian 6).

`ssh server1` (wrong output):

```
Press a Key 27
Press a Key 91
Press a Key 66
```

`ssh server2` (correct output):

```
Press a Key 519
```

Am I missing something in the code or in the terminal? What could be the problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(void)
{
 WINDOW *_window = initscr();
 int _rows;
 int _cols;

 cbreak();

 /* Accept all keys */
 keypad(_window, true);

 /* Don't echo things that are typed */
 noecho();

 /* Get the screen dimensions */
 getmaxyx(_window, _rows, _cols);

 /* Don't display cursor */
 curs_set(0);

 for (;;)
 {
   printw("Press a Key ");
   refresh();
   int key = wgetch(_window);
   printw("%d \n", key);
 }

 endwin();

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the TERM environment variable set to on the servers?

Comment: `server1`: screen-256color, `server2`: `xterm`. Apparently it has something to do with tmux. Detaching the tmux session works great. However, still would be great to know if there is a workaround that can be implemented in the code.

Comment: I don't think so, the key mapping is determined by the TERM variable. You could try setting TERM=xterm on server1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are using the `screen` command and the `TERM` variable is set to screen-256color.

I thought `screen -a`, which uses more termcaps, might work, but it doesn't.

The only way I have found is to set `TERM` to `xterm` so you could set this in your xterm or in the program like this.

```
 setenv("TERM","xterm",1);
```

This is not an ideal solution, it will only work with terminals like xterm, but it is a workaround for your particular problem.